express.js not sending error response when using pipeline
In the following code, I'm forcing an error. GOT error is printed on console so the program is going in catch block, but express never sends a response with statusCode 500.
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.setHeader("Cache-control", `public, max-age=${maxAge}`);

    await pipeline(got.stream(someUrl), res);
  } catch (error) {
    const errMsg =
      error instanceof RequestError
        ? `GOT Request Error ${error.message}`
        : "Some other Error " + (error as Error).message;

    console.error(errMsg);

    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

Here is a screenshot from client

Environment:

Nodejs v22.4.1

Expected result: express should send response with statusCode 500.

What is the error that is reported?

Just GOT request Error is printed on console. Screenshot

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@DarkBee I've only added the screenshot of the api testing client. Wouldn't have been possible to explain it any other way

try console.log(error) ... you may get more info

@JaromandaX Thats not the question. I'm forcing the error. The problem here is that express is not sending response

Oh, right - sorry res.sendStatus(500).end()?

@JaromandaX Nope, same result

I wonder if pipeline is somehow messing up res

maybe it's the client.. what happens when you use curl or browser

@traynor same result. Express doesn't send response.

and if you hardcode only res.sendStatus(500);? if that works, then it's  the pipeline part..

@traynor yup, its the pipeline. I'm getting 500 status code after removing pipeline

yeah, it's the pipeline: stream.pipeline destroys writable stream when error is occurred (also in the docs

@traynor So when an error occurs pipeline is closing all the streams

Is there any workaround for this problem?

yes... looks like not at the moment..

@traynor If you've used golang, does io.copy have the same behaviour?

this comment is the closest thing to a workaround https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26311#issuecomment-468485652 ... i.e. don't use pipeline :p

@JaromandaX , looks like this is the way to go. Or maybe I move this service to golang once I test whether golang has the same problem or not.

@Inder not familiar with go, so can't tell
